# Maxima: define columns of matrix as a vector

Tags: matrix, maxima

In Maxima I want to define vectors using the columns of randomly generated matrix where not only the entries but also the number of rows and columns is random. My code so far:

```
n:2+random(5);
m:2+random(5);
h[i,j]:=5-random(11);    
M:genmatrix(h,n,m);
```

The number of rows/colums can ranges from 2 to 6 (not neccesarily n=m) and the entries are random integers from -5 to 5.

I can now use

```
v1:col(M,1);
```

to define the vector v1 as the first column of the matrix M, but since I don't know how many columns there are I tried this:

```
for i thru n do (vi:col(Mt,i));
```

This returns "Done" but when I enter

```
v1;
```

I just get "v1" as the result and not the first column of the matrix. With

```
for i thru n do (disp (v[i]=col(Mt,i)));
```

I can get Maxima to display all the columns as vectors but again I get just "v1" as the result. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: (1) It's not useful here to use an array function for generating a random matrix because an array function is a memoizing function, and therefore you'll get the same result every time. Try this: `h: lambda([i, j], 5 - random(11));` (that works because lambda expressions aren't memoizing). (2) I don't understand what you want to do with the columns. Are you trying, for example, to create a list containing the columns? or something else?

Comment: @RobertDodier this is supposed to be an excercise for students which I want to implement in STACK for moodle. In the exercise I want to give them n randomly generated vectors and ask them if these vectors are linearly (in)dependent. Thus my goal was to create this matrix (calculate the rank for obvious reasons), extract the vectors and present them to my students. Using the array is not a big problem here, as every time a student does the excercise it will generate a new result.

Comment: OK, thanks for the update. I'll post an answer based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this code right now but I believe this or something pretty similar should work.

Here is a way to generate a random matrix and then extract the columns of the matrix. I don't know if you want to present the columns as column vectors or as row  vectors. Maxima doesn't really have a way to represent row and column vectors as distinct types. Instead for a column vector, I'll obtain a matrix of 1 column, and for a row vector, I'll obtain a list.

```
[m, n]: [2 + random(5), 2 + random(5)];
h: lambda ([i, j], random(11) - 5) $
M: genmatrix (h, m, n);
```

Here is a list comprising the columns of M as 1-column matrices:

```
makelist (col (M, k), k, 1, n);
```

Here is a list comprising the columns of M as lists:

```
args (transpose (M));
```

Comment: This does work both for Maxima and it also translates directly to STACK, thank you very much!